Which software OPEN Firebird 2.0 database into FREE db management Tool?
Need help in finding out Free Tool for firebird 2.0 database?
Can anyone has idea for this tool availability and link?
I have database in Windows Platform and I have few store procedure written there

On official site you can find a quite big list of GUI tools. Some of them are free. Some (such as IBExpert) has a free limited edition.
I personally don't need GUI in most cases so isql is fine. And it is as free as Firebird itself.

I used a lot firebird back in the 90s
it has triggers, functions, procedures,
like a real database
and it (at least back then) is free.
the link is
https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-0/#Win32
for windows

AFAIU they asks not about the server itself but about some fancy and easy to use GUI tool.

very interesting thanks for the clarification, back on the day there was only the native gui provided by firebird
